# Why does bash suppress stdout when exit 0 in ERR trap?

Tags: bash

I was experimenting with setting up an ERR trap in bash and noticed some strange behaviour. Bash seems to not output my `echo` command to the console when I run this script if the exit code is `0`, however, if the exit code is non-zero, then the text is outputted. Is this a bug in bash? Or is there some explanation for this?

./testing.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eE

handleerror() {
  echo "TEST"
  exit 0
}
trap "handleerror" ERR

OUTPUT=$(mkdir test/test 2>&1)
```

If I run the script above, it outputs nothing. If I change the `exit 0` line to `exit 1`, I see the following:

```
> ./testing.sh
TEST
```

For reference:

```
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: the output isn't suppressed; it's captured by the command substitution. Changing the exit status of `handleerror` changes the number of times it gets called: once inside the command substitution, and once *outside*. Run `bash -x testing.sh` to see the difference.

---

You have to consider when `handlerror` actually gets called. The failure of `mkdir` triggers the call, and since `handleerror` is called inside the command substitution, its output is captured and assigned to `OUTPUT`. If you add `echo "$OUTPUT"` to the end of the script, you'll see

```
mkdir: test: No such file or directory
TEST
```

as the output of the script. This line executes because the 0 exit status of `handleerror` prevents `set -e` from exiting the script early.

Now, change `exit 0` to `exit 1`. The sequence starts the same: `mkdir` fails, `handleerror` is called, and its output is captured by the command substitution. But, now the exit status of `handleerror` itself is 1, which makes the exit status of the command substitution and also the assignment statement 1 as well. This does two things: it causes `set -e` to abort the script before `echo "$OUTPUT"` runs, and it causes `handleerror` to run a *second* time. Now when you run the script, all you see is

```
TEST
```

resulting from the second call to `handleerror`.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I think my mental model isn't matching what is actually happening here. Time to read up on command substitution.